# proc-fs - single call back function for several files

Tags: c, linux-kernel, procfs

I have some problems with `proc-filesystem`.
Before `Kernel 3.10` the `proc-fs` `read` and `write` functions had an argument `void *data` which allowed to use a single call back function for several files. In the read and write functions from `struct file_operations` such argument is missing and I have no idea how to solve.

Answer (score 1):

works fine with proc_create_data and PDE_DATA(file_inode(filp)) macro